# Docker Run IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/test2/diversity/file1'

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I have a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 16.04.6 on it. I have this test directory:

```
  ls -hal
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Apr  9 09:21 diversity
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  473 Apr  9 09:21 diversity_test.py
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  145 Apr  9 09:26 dockerfile
```

there are two files in `diversity` directory which i want to compare and find their difference. the code in `diversity_test.py` is:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  #modules
  import difflib
  from pathlib import Path
  #modules

  #variables
  path1=Path('/media/test2/diversity/file1')
  path2=Path('/media/test2/diversity/file2')

  text1 = [l.strip() for l in open(str(path1))]
  text1.sort(key=lambda x: x.strip('#').rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  text2 = [l.strip() for l in open(str(path2))]
  text2.sort(key=lambda x: x.strip('#').rsplit('.', 1)[0])

  for line in difflib.unified_diff(text1, text2, n=0):
       print line,
```

when i run `diversity_test.py` it shows the difference between 2 files in `diversity` directory and works correctly without any error. but when i create a docker image and run it i got this error:

```
   docker build -t python-diversity .
   docker run python-diversity
       Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "diversity_test.py", line 12, in <module>
         text1 = [l.strip() for l in open(str(path1))]
      IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/test2/diversity/file1'
```

the content of `dockerfile` is:

```
  FROM python:2

  WORKDIR /media/test2

  COPY diversity_test.py .

  RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pathlib

  CMD ["python", "diversity_test.py"]
```

I searched this error about docker but i couldn't find any solution. also I'm new to docker. why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use Path() objects if you're just going to call str() on them. Other than that, Ubuntu comes with Python, so do you really need docker and does your code actually work outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only done a COPY for the Python file, not the directory

Since all files are in the same directory as the Dockerfile, simply `COPY . /media/test2` and forget the WORKDIR

You could also run with a volume mount, which would overwrite any existing data that may have been copied, and this would have the added benefit of not needing to rebuild the image if your files change

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/diversity:/media/test2/diversity python-diversity
```

Comment: how i can copy the directory?

Comment: Well, you've copied the file, so do the same for the directory (COPY directive accepts multiple parameters at once)

Comment: is it possible to add this in dockerfile file instead of bringing in command?

Comment: I gave two separate solutions, although they can be combined, so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: ha i get it now

Comment: Updated for clarity